# Is there way to check if shell script is executed with -x flag

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am trying to check in the script, that if that script is executed with -x flag which is for the debugging for shell scripts.
Is there any way to check that in script itself that -x is set.
I want to conditionally check that and do something if that is set.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use:

```
if [[ $- == *x* ]]; then
  echo "debug"
else
  echo "not debug"
fi
```

From [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Special-Parameters):

> ($-, a hyphen.) Expands to the current option flags as specified upon invocation, by the set builtin command, or those set by the shell itself (such as the -i option).

Comment: @john-kugelman, you removed quotes around `$-` even though it might be blank. Is it safe to assume that even if `$-` expands to an empty string, `[[` will allow it to be compared using `==`?

Comment: @ghoti `[` is shell builtin and `[[` is shell keyword and for the latter you don't need to add quotes. When using single brackets: `[` you would have to add quotes. You can check more details [here](http://serverfault.com/questions/52034/what-is-the-difference-between-double-and-single-square-brackets-in-bash)

Comment: What does `*x*` do?

Answer (score 2):

The portable way to do this (without bashisms like `[[ ]]`) would be

```
case $- in
(*x*) echo "under set -x"
esac
```

Answer (score 2):

You can trap the DEBUG signal, like so:

```
trap "do_this_if_it_is_being_debugged" DEBUG

function do_this_if_it_is_being_debugged() {
...
}
```

Note this needs to be executed **before** the `set -x` is being executed

Answer (score 0):

Look for `xtrace` in `$SHELLOPTS`.

For example:

```
if grep -q xtrace <<<"$SHELLOPTS"; then
    DO_SOMETHING;
fi
```